# Tkinter removing a button from a running program

Tags: python, user-interface, widget, tkinter, destroy

I was trying to create a function that creates and places a button on the screen (with grid) and the button's command would be removing itself (or any other widget) but I've failed to do so.

```
def a(self):
    self.call_button = Tkinter.Button(self.root, text = "Call", command=self.b).grid(row = 5, column = 5)

def b(self):
    self.call_button.destroy()
```

a creates the button and b removes it, but when i call on b it says "NoneType object has no attribute destroy"

How do I go about doing this correctly?

Answer (score 7):

`self.call_button` is set to the result of `grid(row=5, column=5)` and not to the Button..

```
from tkinter import *
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.a()

    def a(self):
        self.call_button = Button(self, text = "Call", command=self.b)
        self.call_button.grid(row=5, column=5) # This is fixing your issue

    def b(self):
        self.call_button.destroy()

root = Tk()
app = App(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, if you do `foo=a().b()`, foo is given the value of `b()`. So, when you do `self.call_button = Button(...).grid(...)`, self.call_button is given the value of `.grid(...)`, which is always `None`.

if you want to keep a reference to a widget,  you need to separate your widget creation from your widget layout. This is a good habit to get into, since those are conceptually two different things anyway. In my experience, layout can change a lot during development, but the widgets I use don't change that much. Separating them makes development easier. Plus, it opens the door for later if you decide to offer multiple layouts (eg: navigation on the left, navigation on the right, etc).